# Embedded Linux flash storage security

Tags: flash, embedded-linux

So a lot of shops selling Boards and hardware for embedded Linux systems talk about how disabling UART and JTAG secures the device.

I was wondering, what prevents an attacker to desolder the NAND, eMMC or whatever the device uses and use an adapter to just browse its files?

Since these embedded devices often have Autoboot enabled and dont even have a keyboard, the NAND / eMMC etc. probably cant be encrypted as that would make Autoboot without password prompt impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe because a person possessing the devices is not an "attacker" but more a "thief"? :-) There is little use of concerning about the security of the device, which has already run into wrong hands. They already have complete physical access to the device and can do whatever they want, including a scenario you've described.

Your last line of the defense would be a complete encryption of the data on your storage. But typically such little devices do not (should not at least) contain any valuable information inside, just because it is easy to steal them. So browsing of the on-board flash will reveal little to nothing.